# android code for getting driving direction

Tags: android, google-maps, maps

i am currently doing an android application that requires getting driving directions. I have both source and destination points latitude and longitude and i got the path between the two points , but i can't get the driving directions . plz help me... the code for path is given below

```
            GeoPoint gp1;
        GeoPoint gp2 = startGP;

        for (int i = 1; i < pairs.length; i++) {
            lngLat = pairs[i].split(",");
            gp1 = gp2;
            // watch out! For GeoPoint, first:latitude, second:longitude
            gp2 = new GeoPoint((int) (Double.parseDouble(lngLat[1]) * 1E6),
                    (int) (Double.parseDouble(lngLat[0]) * 1E6));
            myMapView.getOverlays().add(new DirectionPathOverlay(gp1, gp2));
            Log.d("xxx", "pair:" + pairs[i]);
        }

        myMapView.getOverlays().add(new DirectionPathOverlay(gp2, gp2));

        myMapView.getController().animateTo(startGP);
        myMapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        myMapView.displayZoomControls(true);



}


 private String[] getDirectionData(String srcPlace, String destPlace) {

        String urlString = "http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&hl=en&saddr="
                + srcPlace + "&daddr=" + destPlace
                + "&ie=UTF8&0&om=0&output=kml";
        Log.d("URL", urlString);
        Document doc = null;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        URL url = null;
        String pathConent = "";
        try {

            url = new URL(urlString.toString());
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
            urlConnection.connect();
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            doc = db.parse(urlConnection.getInputStream());

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("LineString");
        for (int s = 0; s < nl.getLength(); s++) {
            Node rootNode = nl.item(s);
            NodeList configItems = rootNode.getChildNodes();
            for (int x = 0; x < configItems.getLength(); x++) {
                Node lineStringNode = configItems.item(x);
                NodeList path = lineStringNode.getChildNodes();
                pathConent = path.item(0).getNodeValue();
            }
        }
        String[] tempContent = pathConent.split(" ");
        return tempContent;
    }
```

DirectionPathOverlay.java

```
     public class DirectionPathOverlay extends Overlay {
private GeoPoint gp1;
private GeoPoint gp2;
public DirectionPathOverlay(GeoPoint gp1, GeoPoint gp2) {
    this.gp1 = gp1;
    this.gp2 = gp2;
}

@Override
public boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow,
        long when) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Projection projection = mapView.getProjection();
    if (shadow == false) {
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        Point point = new Point();
        projection.toPixels(gp1, point);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        Point point2 = new Point();
        projection.toPixels(gp2, point2);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(2);
        canvas.drawLine((float) point.x, (float) point.y, (float) point2.x,
                (float) point2.y, paint);
    }
    return super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow, when);
}

@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);
}

}
```

Comment: check these SO posts http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643993/how-to-display-a-route-between-two-geocoords-in-google-maps and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023669/j2me-android-blackberry-driving-directions-route-between-two-locations/2023685#2023685

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612533/android-drivingdirections-removed-since-api-1-0-how-to-do-it-in-1-5-1-6][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612533/android-drivingdirections-removed-since-api-1-0-how-to-do-it-in-1-5-1-6

check this

Comment: i don't want to draw the path. i want to get the driving directions

Answer (score 1):

Try this code to show direction to a place from your current location.

```
locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

    if (location != null) {
        System.out.println("Provider " + provider + " has been selected.");
        lat = (double) (location.getLatitude());
        lng = (double) (location.getLongitude());

    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "Cannot get the location");
    }

    final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?" + "saddr="+ lat + "," + lng + "&daddr="+hotelLat+","+hotelLng));
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(intent);
```