# How to make your own map for application on Android?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, arcgis-server

I'm developing a map application for a University on Android. I am using Google Maps API. The problem is that I found Google Maps does not show the buildings. And routing services. I need to show these over the University's total area. How to create geo, the building and routing services in the university?

[Map Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0RTn.jpg)

I mean about polygon and polyline.

Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The Google Maps API **does** contain a way to show buildings and such - `mapView.setSatellite(true)`.  However, I don't know of a way to connect to routing service.  It's been discussed many times here on SO, and it seems that routing is against Google's Terms of Service, or Google removed it.  It is possible to do queries onto web databases, as can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612533/android-drivingdirections-removed-since-api-1-0-how-to-do-it-in-1-5-1-6).  As far as drawing polygons on the map (I *think* that's what you want to do), you can create you own class extending `Overlay` and override `onDraw()` to draw your shapes on the `Canvas`.  Good luck!